# Await javascript recursive function to return true

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

So I'm using puppeteer in nodeJS and I have a function that recursively calls itself until a specified page is correctly loaded:

```
const isPageAccessible = async (page, url) => {
    var pageRes = await page.goto(url, {
        timeout: 10000
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
    if (!pageRes || pageRes.status !== 200) {
        console.log("Website didn't load properly.")
        isPageAccessible(page, url);
    } else {
        console.log("Loaded!")
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that this function is returning undefined after the first recursive call (which is normal as far as I know since async functions must resolve with a value). I want the code to wait until this function resolves with `true`

```
console.log(await isPageAccessible(page,LOGIN_URL));

console.log("Done!")
```

So the console would log "Done!" after the website has been loaded succesfully. Right now it is logging "Done!" even if the website hasn't been loaded since `isPageAccessible` function is returning undefined after the first call.

Any thoughts on how to solve this would be appreciated!

Comment: why not use a loop?

Comment: You're not awaiting the recursive call or forwarding its result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *return* the recursive call up the Promise chain:

```
if (!pageRes || pageRes.status !== 200) {
  console.log("Website didn't load properly.")
  return isPageAccessible(page, url);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead use this npm module,
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request

```
    var request = require('sync-request');
    var res = request('GET', 'http://example.com');
    console.log(res.getBody());
    console.log("Done!")
```

All the statements will be executed one after another after completion.
Lesser code i guess!!

Comment: So do you suggest that OP should drop puppeteer and use sync-request instead?